# Amadeus api return 401 client Credentials are invalid

Tags: amadeus

Amadeus api returns `401 client Credentials are invalid`. Please check the code below. I included symbols `[` and `]` into credential strings.

```
// here xxxxx are placeholders for real credentials (strings)
Amadeus amadeus = Amadeus.builder("[xxxxxx]","[xxxxxx]")
                    .setHostname("test").setHost("test.api.amadeus.com").setSsl(true).setLogLevel("debug").build();

//HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

//FlightDestination[] des = sh.FlightDest();
//id = sh.id();

try {

    FlightDestination[] destination1 = amadeus.shopping.flightDestinations.get(Params.with("origin", "LON"));


    id = destination1[0].getOrigin();
    name = destination1[0].getDestination();
    email = destination1[0].getType();
}catch (ClientException e)
{
    id=e.getMessage();

}catch (NetworkException e)
{
    id = e.getMessage();

}catch (NotFoundException e)
{
    id = e.getMessage();
}catch (ServerException e)
{
   id =  e.getMessage();
}catch (ParserException e)
{
    id = e.getMessage();
}catch (ResponseException e)
{
    id = e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: try removing the [ ] around the credentials, also, don't post your credentials on here

Comment: when I removed [ ] from credentials, my app crashed. Any suggested solution will be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the **[ ]** and you need to replace them by the API_KEY and the API_SECRET that you get following [this guide](https://developers.amadeus.com/quick-start-guide/category?id=77&durl=335&parentId=NaN).

You can find examples using the Java SDK [here](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/code-samples/documentation/1) and [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/amadeus-java).

```
Amadeus amadeus = Amadeus.builder("API_KEY", "API_SECRET").build();


/* Find cheapest destinations from London */

FlightDestination[] flightDestinations = amadeus.shopping.flightDestinations.get(Params.with("origin", "LON"));

System.out.println(flightDestinations[0]);
```