# Amadeus credentials with correct API_KEY and API_SECRET crashed my app

Tags: amadeus

Please help me check this code out, amadeus api with  correct API_KEY and  API_SECRET inside Void doInBackground(Void... voids) of AsyncTask thread crashed my app. i have been try it for a while any suggested solution will be appreciated.

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

```
        Amadeus amadeus = Amadeus.builder("API_KEY","API_SECRET").build();

        try{
            FlightDestination[] destination1 = amadeus.shopping.flightDestinations.get(Params.with("origin", "MAD"));
            if (destination1[0].getResponse().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                id = destination1[0].getType();
                name = destination1[0].getOrigin();
                email = destination1[0].getDestination();
                date1 = destination1[0].getDepartureDate();
                date2 = destination1[0].getReturnDate();
                FlightDestination.Price total= destination1[0].getPrice();
                double x = total.getTotal();
            }
            else { id = "Error";}
        }catch (ClientException e)
        {
            //id=e.getMessage();

        }catch (NetworkException e)
        {
            id = e.getMessage();

        }catch (NotFoundException e)
        {
            id = e.getMessage();
        }catch (ServerException e)
        {
           id =  e.getMessage();
        }catch (ParserException e)
        {
            id = e.getMessage();
        }catch (ResponseException e)
        {
            id = e.getMessage();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);


        Intent data = new Intent(SportsTickets.this, Displayinfo.class);


        data.putExtra("type",id);
        data.putExtra("origin",name);
        data.putExtra("To",email);
        data.putExtra("departureDate", address);
        data.putExtra("total",gender);
        startActivity(data);



        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amadeus api return 401 client Credentials are invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261094/amadeus-api-return-401-client-credentials-are-invalid)

Comment: There isn't much to go on here. What do you get in your crash logs? Readers need an [mcve] to replicate this.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The HostName, the Host and the SSL are already set by the builder of the SDK, you can just do:

```
Amadeus amadeus = Amadeus.builder("API_KEY", "API_SECRET").build();


/* Find cheapest destinations from London */

FlightDestination[] flightDestinations = amadeus.shopping.flightDestinations.get(Params.with("origin", "LON"));

return flightDestinations;
```

Don't forget to replace you API_KEY and your API_SECRET by the ones you get in your workspace, you can follow this [guide](https://developers.amadeus.com/quick-start-guide/category?id=77&durl=335&parentId=NaN) to get them.